# seq with range:

Tags: linux, fish-shell

Is there a simpler way to get this result?

Also what is the syntax in `fish` for adding numbers to an array index before executing the lookup? `arr[$i+1]` did not seem to work...

desired output:

```
1-6
6-11
11-16
etc
```

but it would also be good to know if there was a generic unix tool to get the above output or similar:

```
1-6
7-11
12-16
etc
```

(also acceptable)

```
$ type seqn
seqn is a function with definition
# Defined in /home/xk/.config/fish/functions/seqn.fish @ line 2
function seqn --argument first increment last
    set carr (seq $first $increment $last)
    for i in (seq 1 (count $carr))
        set i1 (pyp "$i+1")
        echo $carr[$i] $carr[$i1]
    end
end
$ for l in (seqn 1 300 3800)
    echo $l | read -l start end
    if test -n $end
        echo $start-$end
    end
end
1-301
301-601
601-901
901-1201
1201-1501
1501-1801
1801-2101
2101-2401
2401-2701
2701-3001
3001-3301
3301-3601
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want a single function to produce the final output, or whether you want one function (`seqn`) dedicated to outputting the boundary values and a separate function to format the output of `seqn`.

I'm going to work on the basis that a single function to print a formatted list of intervals is the goal, which I'll achieve with stepwise adjustments to your original script:

#### The Basics

To start, it's a good idea to declare variables as `--local` inside a function to guarantee that you're not overwriting an existing variable with the same name unless that's your specific intention, which doesn't seem likely to be the case here:

```
function seqn --argument first increment last
    set --local carr ( seq $first $increment $last )
```

Having defined an array, it seems a shame to have to call `seq` a second time just to generate the indices.  Instead, you can loop through the values of the array:

```
    for cval in $carr
```

You referenced a program ([`pyp`](https://github.com/hauntsaninja/pyp)) in the next line that isn't part of `FiSH` nor one that's bundled with macOS as standard.  You can't assume that someone will know what that program does, so a note explaining what it is (and where to obtain it from) will limit the confusion.  Thankfully, you seemed to only use it to increment a numerical value.  Since we're no longer referencing the array's indices, we won't have to perform any arithmetic on them, but I've commented-out the modified line that now demonstrates how to perform `FiSH` arithmetic.

```
        # set i1 ( math $i + 1 )
```

Printing information to `stdout` that is generated output from a function is best done with `printf`, which allows one to control how it is formatted.  It doesn't insert anything you don't tell it to, which includes spaces and newlines.  `echo` is convenient to evaluate variables quickly when debugging.

Using `printf`, we can have each `$cval` item printed to `stdout` twice, separated by a newline character and followed by a hyphen:

```
        printf -- '-%s\n%s' $cval $cval
```

For example, it will output :

```
-1
1
```

which might not look so useful right now.  The next iteration of the loop will print starting immediately after the last printed character of the previous iteration, so the output will now look like this:

```
-1
1-301
301
```

and then this:

```
-1
1-301
301-601
601
```

Then close the `for` loop, and close the function:

```
    end
end
```

Calling `seqn 1 300 3800` results in the following output:

```
-1
1-301
301-601
601-901
901-1201
1201-1501
1501-1801
1801-2101
2101-2401
2401-2701
2701-3001
3001-3301
3301-3601
3601
```

The first and last lines are consequences of how the formatting was achieved, and can be easily rectified by iterating over all the `$carr` values except the first and the last.  Instead, we deal with these two separately by bringing them outside of the `for` loop, printing the respective values immediately prior to entering and immediately after exiting the loop:

```
function seqn --argument first increment last
    set --local carr ( seq $first $increment $last )
    printf -- '%s' $carr[1]
    for cval in $carr[2..-2]
        # set i1 ( math $i + 1 )
        printf -- '-%s\n%s' $cval $cval
    end
    printf -- '-%s' $carr[-1]
end
```

Calling `seqn 1 300 3800` now outputs the desire result:

```
1-301
301-601
601-901
901-1201
1201-1501
1501-1801
1801-2101
2101-2401
2401-2701
2701-3001
3001-3301
3301-3601
```

#### Improvements

The above function is what one would term a *naive* implementation, in that it is essentially the most basic formulation for the algorithm that exposes each thought process along the way towards achieving the objective.  Whilst naive implementations are generally easy-to-follow and simple to understand what's happening at each line of the script, it doesn't necessarily result in the most efficient way to do something nor the one with the fewest lines of code.  Which of these attributes ends up being the most important will be up to you, but you'll only have the option to choose once you know what they are.

Consider the following array defined like so:

```
> set A 1 2 3 4 5
```

Printing two copies of this list that groups them together by index is not obviously achievable without looping through them.  That is, we wish to achieve the following output:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

without having to iterate through the array ourselves.  Here are some common things one might try:

```
> echo $A $A
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

> echo $A$A
11 21 31 41 51 12 22 32 42 52 13 23 33 43 53 14 24 34 44 54 15 25 35 45 55

> echo {$A,$A}
1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 4 2 5 2 1 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 1 4 2 4 3 4 4 4 5 4 1 5 2 5 3 5 4 5 5 5
```

If you're not familiar with [*Cartesian Products*](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#combining-lists-cartesian-product) in the context of the shell, it's worth learning about them.  That said, that reference document isn't exhaustive, and doesn't contain the solution we're after, so I'll just tell you:

```
> echo $A{,}
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

This is incredibly efficient and directly relevant to the purpose of `seqn`.  If I borrow the line from the `seqn` function that prints a single iteration of `$carr` using the `printf` command, namely:

```
printf -- '-%s\n%s' $cval $cval
```

and substitute the arguments with the cartesian product operating on `$A`, then you can see why this is useful:

```
> printf -- '-%s\n%s' $A{,}
-1
1-2
2-3
3-4
4-5
5
```

As before, we will handle the first and last items of the array separately, but this can replace the entire `for` loop:

```
function seqn --argument first increment last
    set --local carr ( seq $first $increment $last )
    printf -- '%s' $carr[1]
    printf -- '-%s\n%s' $carr[2..-2]{,}
    printf -- '-%s' $carr[-1]
end
```

This might not seem obvious now if `printf` is not familiar to you, but these can combine and simplify into a single call:

```
function seqn --argument first increment last
    set --local carr ( seq $first $increment $last )
    printf '%s-%s\n' $carr[1] $carr[2..-2]{,} $carr[-1]
end
```

#### Final Tweaks (*for the obsessive*)

Calling `seqn` is designed to output intervals (ranges) of numbers where the values of the equivalent call to `seq` serve to become the boundary values of these intervals.  Therefore, to me, it seems like the output from the following call is incomplete:

```
> seqn 1 300 3800
1-301
301-601
601-901
901-1201
1201-1501
1501-1801
1801-2101
2101-2401
2401-2701
2701-3001
3001-3301
3301-3601
```

as I would expect the final range to include:

```
3601-3800
```

Perhaps you disagree, but in case you don't, the solution is a simple tweak to the call made to `seq`.  If `$increment` divides exactly the arithmetic difference `($last - $first)`, then `$last` will appear as the final number in the list generated by `seq`.  If `$increment` does ***not*** divide `($last - $first)`, then `$last` won't appear.

This is inconvenient since appending the value `$last` to the `$carr` array will complete the list in a lot of cases, but in instances where the increment divides the entire range, we'd have two copies of `$last` at the end of `$carr`.  One way to handle this is to do a quick check to see whether we need to append a value or not:

```
set --local carr ( seq $first $increment $last )
[ "$carr[-1]" -ne "$last" ]
and set --append carr $last
```

That's a perfectly good way to do it, and it's clear what we're doing.
But I'm going to make the call to `seq` with the calculated value of `($last - 1)` in place of `$last`.  The resulting `$carr` array definitely ***won't*** contain `$last`, but, importantly, every other number that would have otherwise been present will still be present (I'm assuming we're dealing only with integers).  Then I can append the value `$last` as part of the array declaration:

```
set --local carr ( seq  $first $increment (
                   math $last - 1 ) ) $last
```

Another option is to set the `-t` parameter for `seq`, which instructs it to terminate the list with whatever string value is passed as the parameter:

```
set --local carr ( seq -t $last $first $increment (
                   math   $last - 1 ) )
```

The reason I'm bothering with this is that it allows me to do away with declaring a variable at the function level, and create a temporary variable attached to a single command only, in this case, the `printf` command:

```
function seqn
    I=(  seq -t $argv[3 1 2] (
         math   $argv[3] - 1 )
    ){,} printf '%s-%s\n' $I[2..-2]
end
```

I've replaced the named argument variables with the default `$argv` simply for brevity.  The `printf` call has also been simplified a little more by moving the cartesian product so that it operates on the temporary variable at the point of declaration, which creates exactly two copies of every item in the list allowing us to do the simpler manoeuvre of omitting one value at either end.

Calling `seqn 1 300 3800` now outputs:

```
1-301
301-601
601-901
901-1201
1201-1501
1501-1801
1801-2101
2101-2401
2401-2701
2701-3001
3001-3301
3301-3601
3601-3800
```